# CSS3 animation twinkle when frame finishes

Tags: image, css, loops, animation

maybe this a repetitive question , but I saw alot of tutorials , but my issue has been remained. I want to make a background image which is moving.I did the code and I got it from different tutorials.but my issue is: when the frame is finished , before showing the image ihave one little twinkle on screen .how can I solve this problem , because I want to have one background which moves from right to left very smoothly.
let me tell you that I have only one image and I want to make loop with this one only.and width of image is greater than my screen.

code:

```css
#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("assets/css/images/day.jpg") repeat-x;
  -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 60s linear infinite;
  animation: backgroundScroll 60s linear infinite;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  z-index: -2;
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
@keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bg">
</div>
```

Comment: what is the width of the div and the width of the image in px ?

Comment: the width of image is 3000 pixel , and width of div , I have not defined.

Comment: I faced another problem which I posted below.if you help me, that will be a greate appreciate for me

Answer (score 1):

The width of the div should be x times the width of the background image. Where x is an integer. Otherwise you will need additional calculations

```css
#bg1, #bg2, #bg3 {
  height: 41px;
  background: url("https://www.google.co.in/logos/doodles/2016/juno-reaches-jupiter-5164229872058368-res.png") repeat-x;
  -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 5s linear infinite;
  animation: backgroundScroll 5s linear infinite;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}


#bg1{
  width: 190px; // 2x width
}

#bg2{
  width: 285px; // 3x width
}

#bg3{
  width: 250px; // random width
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bg1">
</div>

<div id="bg2">
</div>
  
<br>
Wrong width
<div id="bg3">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using another image in my system, it has not showing any little twinkle on screen..can u send me your image.

```css
html{width:100%; height:100%;}
body{width:100%; height:100%; box-sizing: border-box;}
#bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("../images/2.jpg") repeat-x;
  -webkit-animation: backgroundScroll 60s linear infinite;
  animation: backgroundScroll 60s linear infinite;
  background-position: 0px 0px;
  z-index: -2;
}
@-webkit-keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
@keyframes backgroundScroll {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100% 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. but for image did not work.. how can I send my image to u? thanks alot